# Package not activating when running specs

Tags: javascript, jasmine, atom-editor, specifications

I've created a package for Atom called [quick-fold](https://github.com/binaryfunt/quick-fold) that jumps to the next foldable line and folds it on the command `quick-fold:fold-next`. I wanted to start getting into Atom specs so I can run tests on this package, however I've hit this problem where the package is just never activated when running the specs.

**`quick-fold-spec.js`:**

```
describe('QuickFold package', () => {

    let editor, editorView;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await atom.packages.activatePackage('language-javascript');
        await atom.workspace.open('sample.js');

        editor = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor();
        editorView = atom.views.getView(editor);
    });

    describe('when the specs are run', () => {
        it('opens the sample file', () => expect(!editor.isEmpty()).toBe(true));
        // true
    });

    describe('when the quick-fold:fold-next event is triggered', () => {
        beforeEach(async () => {
            // Try to activate package by dispatching command:
            atom.commands.dispatch(editorView, 'quick-fold:fold-next');
            await atom.packages.activatePackage('quick-fold'); // Never resolves
        });

        it('activates the package', () => {
            expect(atom.packages.isPackageActive('quick-fold')).toBe(true);
        });

        it('moves the cursor to a different line number', () => {
            expect(editor.getCursorScreenPosition().row).not.toBe(0);
        });
    });
});
```

But `atom.packages.activatePackage('quick-fold')` never resolves. The package doesn't activate and instead it times out:

`timeout: timed out after 5000 msec waiting for spec promise to resolve`

[image: Spec suite screenshot]

The activation command is set in `package.json`:

```
  "activationCommands": {
    "atom-workspace": "quick-fold:fold-next"
  },
```

so dispatching this should activate the package, and then the `await atom.packages.activatePackage('quick-fold')` should resolve. But the cursor position doesn't change and the package doesn't get activated.

(Note that `atom.packages.activatePackage('quick-fold')` is merely a promise - it doesn't activate the package but it resolves when the package gets activated.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is often the case, I figured it out in the end...

#### 1. The `beforeEach()` function is missing a `runs()`

It should be

```
    beforeEach(async () => {
        await atom.packages.activatePackage('language-javascript');
        await atom.workspace.open('sample.js');

        runs(() => {
            editor = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor();
            editorView = atom.views.getView(editor);

            return activationPromise = atom.packages.activatePackage('quick-fold');
        });
    });
```

where the `runs()` function returns a promise on activation of the package.

From [the docs](https://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction#section-31):

> Specs are written by defining a set of blocks with calls to `runs`, which usually finish with an asynchronous call.

I'm too tired right now to understand exactly what that means but it rings true here.

#### 2. The activation commands in `package.json` should be based on `atom-text-editor`

I.e., not `atom-workspace`

```
  "activationCommands": {
    "atom-text-editor": "quick-fold:fold-next"
  },
```

This is probably because we have `atom.commands.dispatch(editorView, 'quick-fold:fold-next')` where the commands are dispatched to `editorView = atom.views.getView(editor)` instead of the Atom workspace.

---

#### Refactored - the "standard" way of doing it

```
describe('QuickFold package', () => {

    let editor, editorView, activationPromise;

    const foldNext = async (callback) => {
        atom.commands.dispatch(editorView, 'quick-fold:fold-next');
        await activationPromise;
        return callback();
    };

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await atom.packages.activatePackage('language-javascript');
        await atom.workspace.open('sample.js');

        runs(() => {
            editor = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor();
            editorView = atom.views.getView(editor);

            return activationPromise = atom.packages.activatePackage('quick-fold');
        });
    });

    describe('when the specs are run', () => {
        it('opens the sample file', () => expect(!editor.isEmpty()).toBe(true));
    });

    describe('when the quick-fold:fold-next event is triggered', () => {
        it('activates the package', () => {
            return foldNext(() => expect(atom.packages.isPackageActive('quick-fold')).toBe(true));
        });

        it('moves the cursor to a different line number', () => {
            return foldNext(() => expect(editor.getCursorScreenPosition().row).not.toBe(0));
        });
    });
});
```